# Shared resource for partial in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Premise: I'm quite new to Rails. I'm trying to render a partial in the application layout that will have to display some `Event` objects. The partial will have to be displayed in every page of the application (it's basically a sidebar). I am aware that I should pass a local variable to the partial, like

```
    <%= render partial: "shared/aside", locals: {events: @events} %>
```

But this will only work if I define `@events` in every single controller of the application. Is there a way of setting it globally?
It might be worth noting that events might not be the only resource needed to the partial.

Comment: hello, could you add how `@events` look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do a before action in the application controller. The before action would go at the top of the file, the private method at the bottom

```
class ApplicationController < ActiveController::Base
# Place at top of file
before_action :set_events

...your other code...

# Place at bottom of file
private

def set_events
 @events = Event.all
end
```

Comment: hello, you could use `helper_method` like http://jgaskins.org/blog/2014/08/25/better-alternative-to-rails-before_action-to-load-objects instead of loading data in `before_action`

Comment: Well he is specifying which methods to apply the before_action to inside an individual controller, you wanted it site wide so I am unsure if that solves this.